# selenium set attribute using python and javascript executor

Tags: python, selenium

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="checkoutAfterCaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeWwRkUAAAAAOBsau7KpuC9AV-6J8mhw4AjC3Xz" data-size="invisible"><div class="grecaptcha-badge" data-style="bottomright"</div>
```

Im trying to set the attribute of this HTML element to something else im using selenium but its not working can anyone take quick look and see what im doing wrong? Im using javascript executor. Im trying to change the data-sitekey

```
key = Driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.g-recaptcha')
Driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-sitekey');",key)
```

Comment: In your code you're setting class to be equal to `g-recaptcha`, but it's already its class judging by your css selector, so even if it's working you will never notice any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set data-sitekey attribute to some value not class.

```
key = Driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.g-recaptcha')
Driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-sitekey', 'somevalue');",key)
```